# Is there a way to check tail columns from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to see some columns in a dataframe but from the tail of columns. Not rows.

Usually when you want to check the dataframe the following will be the easiest way to do.

```
print(df.head(5))

             Au        Ag        Al        As  ...        Zn        Zr  SAMPLE    Alt
    0 -0.657577 -1.154902 -0.638272  1.541579  ...  0.477121  0.462398   GH101    phy
    1 -2.431798  0.149219 -0.537602  1.086360  ...  1.681241 -0.301030   GH102  ad-ag
    2 -2.568636  0.178977 -0.346787  1.025306  ...  1.681241 -0.154902   GH103  ad-ag
    3 -2.455932  0.722634 -0.568636  1.378398  ...  1.113943 -0.301030   GH104  ad-ag
    4 -3.698970 -1.522879 -0.292430  1.045323  ...  1.556303 -0.154902   GH105    phy
```

However, I would like to check the columns on the right side of this print result (from "Alt" to leftwards), and check 5 columns for example.

Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Maybe `df[df.columns[-5:]]`?

Comment: Sorry for the duplication. It seems the way I searched wasn't good enough. Also I didn't realize I can use iloc for selecting columns backwards. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `iloc` for this, which allows integer-based indexing of a DataFrame. It takes the syntax `[i, j]`, where `i` indexes rows and `j` indexes columns, and allows slicing. (docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html))

In this case, you want all the rows and the last five columns, so you can do this:

```
df.iloc[:, -5:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df[df.columns[-5:]]
```

or:

```
df.T.iloc[-5:]
```

To select the last five elements (columns).

For rows you can do:

```
df.iloc[-5:]
```

Comment: That is the equivalent of `df.tail(5)`, and selects the last 5 *rows*. OP wants the last 5 *columns*.